# How to get the time elapsed between two records?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, timer

I am using the code below to generate the active user window title I save this information as well as the process name, time the application was started and duration.
My problem is that when I run the code instead of saving data of window titles when the window title changes it saves every second which it should however the conditions I had set are not being applied. What am I doing wrong.

```
 private void GetTotalTimer()
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            IntPtr hwnd = APIFunc.getforegroundWindow();
            Int32 pid = APIFunc.GetWindowProcessID(hwnd);
            Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);

            appName = p.ProcessName;
            const int nChars = 256;
            int handle = 0;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
            handle = GetForegroundWindow();
            appltitle = APIFunc.ActiveApplTitle().Trim().Replace("\0", "");

            //if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
            //{
            //    string strbuff = Buff.ToString();

            //    StrWindow = strbuff;

                #region insert statement
                try
                {
                    if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        Conn.Open();
                    }
                    if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select top 1 [Window Title] From TimerLogs ORDER BY [Time of Event] DESC", Conn);
                        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                        startTime = DateTime.Now;
                        string time = now.ToString();
                        if (!reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            reader.Close();


                            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [TimerLogs] values(@time,@appName,@appltitle,@Elapsed_Time,@userName)", Conn);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appName", appName);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appltitle", appltitle);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Elapsed_Time", blank.ToString());
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Conn.Close();
                        }
                        else if(reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            reader.Read();
                            if (appltitle != reader.ToString())
                            {
                                reader.Close();
                                endTime = DateTime.Now;
                                appduration = endTime.Subtract(startTime);

                                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [TimerLogs] values (@time,@appName,@appltitle,@Elapsed_Time,@userName)", Conn);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", time);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appName", appName);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appltitle", appltitle);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Elapsed_Time", appduration.ToString());
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                reader.Close();
                                Conn.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
          //}

                #endregion
                ActivityTimer.Start();
                Processing = "Working";

        }
```

and this is my result
    [image]

In the code above my logic is that. The code logs when the application was started as starttime if there is no other data in the table if there is data then the code checks if the current application name does not match the application name in the database table. If this is true it is then to calculate the duration however it is inserting data every second

Answer (score 0):

You have the code:

```
 if (appltitle != reader.ToString())
```

...which is never going to evaluate to true (unless you have an application called System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader) since `appltitle` contains the title of your application and reader.ToString() is just converting a `SqlDataReader` to a string, which will quite literally be "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader".

What you need to do is compare the current `appltitle` to the data value being read:

```
 // if able to read a row
 if (reader.Read())
 {  
     int ColumnIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("[Window Title]");
     // This gets you the value of the Window Title column in the current row
     if (appltitle != reader.GetString(ColumnIndex))
     {
         // Do Stuff Here
     }                  
 }
```

i.e. You need to actually read from the reader using `Read()`, then examine the contents of the [Window Title] column.